Uniform Continuity Proof Check
I don't have much experience writing proofs and this particular problem for my Real Analysis course has been giving me a lot of difficulty. The course is being taught by a professor who just rewrites the textbook verbatim on the board and doesn't explain much. Please forgive the ugly formatting, as this is my first time using StackExchange.
The Question States:
Give an example of sets $A$ and $B$ and a continuous function $f:A\cup B\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and uniformly continuous on $B$, but not uniformly continuous on $A\cup B$.
The proof I have written so far:
Let $A=(-\infty,2)$ and $B=[2,\infty]$, and let $f$ be the continuous piecewise function $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2-3, & x<2 \\ 2x-3, & x\geq 2\end{cases}$ (I chose this function because I know it is a continuous piecewise function).
First, consider $A$. On the interval $(-\infty,2)$, $f(x)=x^2-3$. Thus, for $f$ to be uniformly continuous on $A$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there must exist a $\delta>0$ such that if $x,y\in A$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. For $A$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|(x^2-3)-(y^2-3)|=|x^2-y^2|=|x+y||x-y|.$$
Since $x$ and $y$ are both less than $2$, $x+y$ must always be less than $4$. Thus, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 4|x-y|$. Choose $\delta=\epsilon/4$. Then with $|x-y|<\epsilon/4$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 4|x-y|<4(\epsilon/4)=\epsilon. $$
For every $\epsilon>0$, choosing $\delta=\epsilon/4$ will ensure that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Hence, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$.
Next, consider $B$. On the interval $[2,\infty)$, $f(x)=2x-3$. Thus, for $f$ to be uniformly continuous on $B$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there must exist a $\delta>0$ such that if $x,y\in B$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. For $B$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|(2x-3)-(2y-3)|=2|x-y|.$$
Choose $\delta=\epsilon/2$. Then with $|x-y|<\epsilon/2$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=2|x-y|<2(\epsilon/2)=\epsilon.$$
For every $\epsilon>0$, choosing $\delta=\epsilon/2$ will ensure that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Hence, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B$.
Now, consider $A\cup B$. Choosing $\epsilon=1$, for $f$ to be not uniformly continuous at $A\cup B$, it must be shown that for any $\delta>0$, there are $x$ and $y$ in $A\cup B$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq 1$. However, consider $x=2-\delta/3\in A$ and $y=2+\delta/3\in B$. Choosing $\delta>1$,
$$
|x-y|=|(2-\delta/3)-(2+\delta/3)|=2\delta/3<\delta.
$$
For
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(2-\delta/3)-f(2+\delta/3)|=|(1-4\delta/3+\delta^2/9)-(1+2\delta/3)|=|-2\delta+\delta^2/9|.$$
Choose some $\delta>1/2$, such as $\delta=19/36$.
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|-2(19/36)+1/36| \approx 1.03.$$
Since $1.03>1$, there exists an $x$ and $y$ in $A\cup B$ where $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq 1$. Hence, $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $A\cup B$, despite $A$ and $B$ both being uniformly continuous.

I feel like the final part of the proof is where I begin to lose understanding of what exactly needs to be true for f to not be uniformly continuous at the union. This class has been my first exposure to proofs, and I've been struggling all the way through. If I am approaching the proof incorrectly altogether, I am willing to hear out alternative examples or approaches.
Thank you in advance.

Your $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $A$. It is not true that $|x+y|\le 4$. You change $A$ to $(0,2)$ to make it uniformly continuous on $A$, but then, $f$ would be uniformly continuous on $A\cup B$ also.

You could try being a little more creative with $A,B$. For example, define $f$ to be $0$ on the set $[0,1] \cup [2,3] \cup [4,5] \cup ...$. Now select $B$ (also closed) such that $f$ is $1$ on $B$, but the sets in $B$ (which could be vacuously simple) get 'closer and closer' to $A$.

@copper.hat - $f$ has to be continuous on $A\cup B$, though not uniformly so. If $f(A) = 0$ and $f(B) = 1$, that requires the two sets to maintain a respectful distance from each other.

@PaulSinclair The two sets can be arbitrarily close, continuity is a local property.

@copper.hat - Doh! Obviously, I was making an assumption that you had already stepped around.
